# Querying Path in Neo4j, How To Show Node/Edge Info Only Once?

Tags: graph, neo4j

If a simple query for a path between two nodes was made, say,

```
MATCH (m{name:'m'}), (n{name:'n'}),
   path = (m)-[:SOME_EDGE*]->(n)
RETURN path

EDIT: 
(example result)
...
segments: [
{
   start: {
      id: 1
      labels: [lbl1, lbl2, ...],
      properties: [p1, p2, ...]
   }
   end: { ... }
   properties: { ... }

},
{
   start: {
     id: 1
     labels: [lbl1, lbl2, ...]          <--- duplicate
     properties: [p1, p2, ...]          <--- duplicate
   }   
},
...
]
```

the result generated contains many duplicates of properties/types/IDs of sames nodes/edges again and again, and this gets worse when there are cycles in the paths.

I googled and found that I could use projections like

```
return [node in nodes(path) | id(node)] as pathNodes, 
   [r in relationships(path) | id: id(r), type: type(r)] as rels

(Example result)
   { 
      pathNodes: [1,2,3],
      rels: {id:101,type:'SOME_EDGE'},{id:102,type:'SOME_EDGE'}
   },
   {
      pathNodes: [1,2,1,3],
      rels: ...
   }, ...
```

But how to add nodes/relationships info (just once for one entity) to the result above?

Is there any way to get this done in a single query?

Comment: Can you give an example of your duplicates from the first query ? Because in your second query the result is the same, you just have changed the result's projection ...

Comment: Suppose you have only two nodes and there are three edges between them. Every edge will have  'start', 'end', and 'relationship (rel type and rel's properties).' Here 'start' and 'end' are nodes repeated meaninglessly.

Comment: So what is the result format you want ? A distinct result of node's path, so in your example only one result with your two nodes ?

Comment: In the second code above, I chose only id(node) but what I really want is the complete node info (like the first code, but just once) put together with edges. If I chose not to use projections for nodes, the whole node info would be repeated for every appearance along the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect paths, nodes and relationships into a distinct lists, and then make a maps based on them using [`apoc.map.setKey`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#map-functions) function:

```
MATCH path = (A)-[*]->(B)
UNWIND nodes(path) AS n
UNWIND relationships(path) AS r
WITH 
  collect(DISTINCT path) as paths,
  collect(DISTINCT n) AS nodes, 
  collect(DISTINCT r) AS rels
RETURN
  [p IN paths | {
    nodes: [n IN nodes(p) | id(n)],
    rels: [r IN relationships(p) | id(r)]
  }] as paths,
  reduce(acc={}, n IN nodes | apoc.map.setKey(acc, toString(id(n)), n)) as nodes,
  reduce(acc={}, r IN rels | apoc.map.setKey(acc, toString(id(r)), r)) as rels
```

Answer (score 0):

stdob-- was right about UNWIND and COLLECT and didn't really need to use APOC.

I came up with a solution by myself months ago and came here today so I chose his/her answer and also post my solution without APOC here.

UNWIND and re-COLLECT is the key

```
MATCH p=(m{name:'m'})-[:'SOME_EDGE'|:'SOME_OTHER_EDGE'*1..2]->(n{name:'n'})
WITH {
  pathNodes: [node IN nodes(p) | ID(node)], 
  rels: [r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | {id:ID(r),ty:TYPE(r)}] 
} AS path, p
UNWIND NODES(p) AS node
RETURN {paths:COLLECT(path), nodes: COLLECT(DISTINCT{id:ID(node),name:node.name})}
```